# Issues using perl modules and passing variables into subroutines

Tags: perl, module

So I am new to the perl programing language and I want to get myself acquainted with creating, using, and passing parameters into modules. I made a hello world module that takes as a parameter two string variables from the main.pl testing program, one that says "hello" and another that says "world" and prints them out. Every time I try running main.pl I keep getting errors and I have spent many days trying to get this otherwise simple program to function correctly.

This is the code for my main.pl function:

```
use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::Bin;
use test;
use strict;
my $firststring = "hello";
my $secondstring = "world";
test::printthing(\$firststring, \$secondstring);
```

And this is the coded for my test.pm module:

```
package test;

use strict

use Exporter;
our @ISA = qw/Exporter/;
our @EXPORT = qw/&main/;

sub printthing{
    my $firstword = $_[0];
    my $secondwork = $_[1];
    print"$firstword\n";
    print"$secondword\n";
}1;
```

Comment: 1) Missing semicolon on `use strict` ... seriously? If it's a typo in posting then note that it's better to copy-paste. So that there are no such typos. 2) You need `use Exporter qw(import);` if you want to actually export names to the caller.  3) You don't `EXPORT` the function `printthing`, have no function `main` which you attempt to export, and shouldn't have `&` in front of function names in `EXPORT`.  These things wouldn't throw errors in the example you show but are wrong. 4) Is the module `test.pm`  in the same directory with the script?  ///  _Please show exact errors_

Comment: Should always have both `use warnings;` and `use strict;` in all units -- in the main program as well as in modules

Comment: `$secondwork` and `$secondword` is another trivial error.

Answer (score 1):

- You're missing the semicolon from the end of your `use strict` line in the module.
- You try to export the `main()` subroutine, but your module doesn't have a subroutine called `main()`.
- You pass references to your variables to the subroutine but don't dereference them before printing them.

For the final point, you can either continue to pass in references, but dereference before printing.

```
test::printthing(\$firststring, \$secondstring);

# and then in the subroutine...

print"$$firstword\n";
print"$$secondword\n";
```

Or, you could just pass in the variables and ignore references completely.

```
test::printthing($firststring, $secondstring);

# and then in the subroutine...

print"$firstword\n";
print"$secondword\n";
```